# Why does this polymorphic operation compile?

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

I dont understand why the following code compiles -

```
ICollection selecteditems = iselect.Snapshot();
foreach (Content c in selecteditems)
    ....
```

As you might expect, `Snapshot()` returns a collection of `Content`s, but `ICollection` contains no info on types, let alone the `Content` type. This scope of the program should not know about `Content`, so why does it compile?

Answer (score 3):

Because the code you posted is equivlent to the following code

```
ICollection selecteditems = iselect.Snapshot();

foreach (object temp in selecteditems)
{
    Content c = (Content)temp; //This is fine at compile-time but fails at run-time.
    ...
}
```

`object` is castable to any other object and because `ICollection` only has `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>` the type of temp will be `object`. Try this with a sealed class that implements `IEnumerable<T>` and you will see a compile time error.

```
sealed class Foo : IEnumerable<Foo>
{
    IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplmentedException();
    }

    object IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

class Bar
{
}
```

Which would have a compile time error on

```
IEnumerable<Foo> selecteditems = iselect.Snapshot();
foreach (Bar c in selecteditems) //Compile time error.
{
    ...
```

Which would be equivalent to

```
IEnumerable<Foo> selecteditems = iselect.Snapshot();
foreach (Foo temp in selecteditems)
{
    Bar c = (Bar)temp; //This cast fails at compile-time.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it is a important difference that greatly effects the behavior of the code if using lambadas.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I simplified it to just show the C# 5 version.

Answer (score 0):

`ICollection` enumerator will return enumeration of `object`.  During runtime it'll try to cast `object` instance into `Content` instance.  If it can, all is great, if it cannot, type casting exception is thrown.